# How to flowtype cover this code in a function with dereferenced object fields

Tags: flowtype

I'm new to flow, any trying to cover some of my functions, however often I have these snippets where I extract fields form an object based on some condition. But I'm struggling to cover them with flow.

```
const _join = function ( that: Array<Object>, by: string, index: number) {
        that.forEach((thatOBJ: {[string]: any}, i: number)=>{
            let obj: {[string]: any} = {};
            for (let field: string in thatOBJ) {
                if (field !== by) {
                    obj[`${index.toString()}_${field}`] = thatOBJ[field]; // NOT COVERED
                } else {
                    obj[field] = thatOBJ[field]; // NOT COVERED
                }
                that[i] = obj;
            }
        });
}
```

The array `that` in this code is a data array so can really be in any format of mongodb data. 
Any ideas on what to add to make the two lines which are not covered by flow covered?
Thanks.

Comment: It seems like since you are dynamically generating certain field names, there would be no way for Flow to typecheck that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few notes...

- This function has a "side effect" since you're mutating `that` rather than using a transformation and returning a new object.
- `Array<Object>` is an `Array` of `any`, bounded by `{}`. There are no other guarantees.
- If you care about modeling this functionality and statically typing them, you need to use unions (or `|`) to enumerate all the value possibilities.
- It's not currently possible to model computed `map` keys in flow.

This is how I'd re-write your `join` function:

```
// @flow

function createIndexObject<T>(obj: { [string]: T }, by: string, index: number): { [string]: T } {
  return Object.keys(obj).reduce((newObj, key) => {
    if (key !== by) {
      newObj[`${index}_${key}`] = newObj[key]
    } else {
      newObj[key] = obj[key]
    }
    return newObj
  }, {})
}

// NO ERROR
const test1: { [string]: string | number } = createIndexObject({ foo: '', bar: 3  }, 'foo', 1)

// ERROR
const test2: { [string]: string | boolean } = createIndexObject({ foo: '', bar: 3  }, 'foo', 1)
```